# Synchronization of a variable

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized

In this program, object `jai` is accessed by a thread, while its also modified by another thread. Is this the right way of working? Is there no need to make the object synchronized?

```
public class SameObjectModification {

    private static int i = 0;

    private static Jai jai;

    static class Jai {

        private final int a;

        public Jai( int a ) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println( "value ==> " + a );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while ( true ) {
                    if ( jai != null )
                        jai.print();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread t2 = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while ( true ) {
                    jai = new Jai( i++ );
                }
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No, it's not. You're accessing state from different threads without synchronization. So you'll have visibility issues.

Comment: It depends what you want. If you want to achieve mutual exclusion then you have to synchronize it..

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, but you can get a unique value of a for every Jai by using atomics.

```
private static AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);

private static Jai jai;

static class Jai {

    private int a;
    public Jai() {
        this.a = i.incrementAndGet();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This thrade save version of your example

```
private static int i = 0;

private static AtomicReference<Jai> jai = new AtomicReference<Jai>();

static class Jai {

    private final int a;

    public Jai( int a ) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println( "value ==> " + a );
    }
}

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while ( true ) {
                Jai tmp = jai.get();
                if ( tmp != null )
                    tmp.print();
            }
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while ( true ) {
                jai.set(new Jai( i++ ));
            }
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

But implementation depends on your porpose.
You should use AtomicReference only for immutable or thread-safe classes.

In other cases you can use different locks, volatile fields, different atomic implementations (such as AtomicLong), or synchronize.

But you should remember that an atomic faster than a lock and a lock faster than synchronize.

Comment: Am wondering why am not getting any exception when I run this code.

Comment: You will not get any exception on your code because operation under reference usually is atomic by CPU architecture (such as x86). But if you run your code on exotic cpu you can get exception.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the variable `jai` is referencing many objects sequentially. In each iteration of the loop in the second thread a new object is created and assigned to the variable. So, synchronizing on `jai` would not help.

If you want to ensure that all objects created by the `t2` thread are processed by `t1`, you need to either lock t1 and wait until `t2` creates an object or use a kind of queue. Read about [java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

More generally, this is an example of [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) problem.